# c# to excel dynamically add dictionary data

Tags: c#, excel, dictionary

I have this report tool that exports data from API to excel and the problem i am having is that within this data there is an dictionary with more data i also want to display in the same row but when i try to export this data it ends up like this in the excel[image]

As you see it ends up as Models.UserDetails thing. how would i properly make this display the values in the dictionary. This is what i have done so far.

```
foreach (var reportItem in model.Entries)
{
    var userDetails= new List<UserDetails>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, UserDetails> entry in reportItem.UserDetails)
    {
        userDetails.Add(entry.Value);
    }

    exportData.ReportDetails.Add(new UserReportExportDetailModel
    {
        ProductGroup = reportItem.ProductGroup,
        UserId = reportItem.ExternalId,
        Country = reportItem.Country,
        Brand = reportItem.Brand,
        FinalScore = reportItem.TotalPoints,
        TimeOfLogin = reportItem.Time,
        Position = reportItem.Position + 1,
        UserDetails = userDetails
    });
}
```

and the UserDetails looks like

```
public class UserDetails
{
    public decimal Points { get; set; } = 0;
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public long LoginId { get; set; }
}
```

So how would i make the UserDetails column in excel display the data inside the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel can't display a list of objects in a single cell, so you need to help him convert that list to something excel understands, such as a string.

Pseudocode:

```
    foreach (var reportItem in model.Entries) {

        var userDetails = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, UserDetails> entry in reportItem.UserDetails)
        {
            userDetails.AppendFormat("{0},{1},{2}", entry.Value.Points, entry.Value.Time, entry.Value.LoginId);
        }
    
        exportData.ReportDetails.Add(new UserReportExportDetailModel
        {
            ProductGroup = reportItem.ProductGroup,
            UserId = reportItem.ExternalId,
            Country = reportItem.Country,
            Brand = reportItem.Brand,
            FinalScore = reportItem.TotalPoints,
            TimeOfLogin = reportItem.Time,
            Position = reportItem.Position + 1,
            UserDetails = userDetails.ToString()
        }); 
   }
```